How to configure azurerm_role_management_policy at resource scope?
I have created different Terraform modules to manage scope at 3 different levels. Subscription, Resource Group and Resource. The first two are working fine since they are quite generic in nature. However for the last one I am facing problem with the scope. Can someone please suggest what should be the way to configure the scope at a specific resource level for allowing me to configure azurerm_role_management_policy rules?


resource "azurerm_role_management_policy" "role_policy_resource" {
  for_each = toset(var.role_definition_names)
  scope              = data.azurerm_key_vault.statickv.id           # Scope of the role management policy
  role_definition_id = data.azurerm_role_definition.roles[each.value].id  # ID of the role definition

  active_assignment_rules {
    expire_after = var.role_policy_rules.active_assignment_rules_expire_after  # Expiration period for active assignments
  }

  eligible_assignment_rules {
    expiration_required = false  # Whether expiration is required for eligible assignments
  }

  activation_rules {
    maximum_duration = var.role_policy_rules.activation_rules_maximum_duration  # Maximum duration for activation
    require_approval = var.role_policy_rules.activation_rules_require_approval   # Whether approval is required for activation
    dynamic "approval_stage" {
      for_each = var.role_policy_rules.activation_rules_require_approval ? ["this"] : []
        content{
          primary_approver {
          object_id = var.role_policy_rules.activation_rules_approver_object_id  # Primary approver for activation
          type = var.role_policy_rules.activation_rules_approver_type  # Type of the primary approver
          }
        }
    }
  }
  notification_rules {
    eligible_assignments {
      admin_notifications {
        notification_level    = var.role_policy_rules.notification_rules_eligible_assignments_admin_notifications_notification_level                     # Notification level for admin notifications
        default_recipients    = var.role_policy_rules.notification_rules_eligible_assignments_admin_notifications_default_recipients                          # Whether to use default recipients for admin notifications
        additional_recipients = var.role_policy_rules.notification_rules_eligible_assignments_admin_notifications_additional_recipients       # Additional recipients for admin notifications
      }
      approver_notifications {
        notification_level    = var.role_policy_rules.notification_rules_eligible_assignments_approver_notifications_notification_level                    # Notification level for approver notifications
        default_recipients    = var.role_policy_rules.notification_rules_eligible_assignments_approver_notifications_default_recipients                          # Whether to use default recipients for approver notifications
        additional_recipients = var.role_policy_rules.notification_rules_eligible_assignments_approver_notifications_additional_recipients       # Additional recipients for approver notifications
      }
      assignee_notifications {
        notification_level    = var.role_policy_rules.notification_rules_eligible_assignments_assignee_notifications_notification_level                     # Notification level for assignee notifications
        default_recipients    = var.role_policy_rules.notification_rules_eligible_assignments_assignee_notifications_default_recipients                         # Whether to use default recipients for assignee notifications
        additional_recipients = var.role_policy_rules.notification_rules_eligible_assignments_assignee_notifications_additional_recipients
      }
    }
    eligible_activations {
      admin_notifications {
        notification_level    = var.role_policy_rules.notification_rules_eligible_activations_admin_notifications_notification_level                     # Notification level for assignee notifications
        default_recipients    = var.role_policy_rules.notification_rules_eligible_activations_admin_notifications_default_recipients                         # Whether to use default recipients for assignee notifications
        additional_recipients = var.role_policy_rules.notification_rules_eligible_activations_admin_notifications_additional_recipients
      }
      assignee_notifications {
        notification_level    = var.role_policy_rules.notification_rules_eligible_activations_assignee_notifications_notification_level                     # Notification level for assignee notifications
        default_recipients    = var.role_policy_rules.notification_rules_eligible_activations_assignee_notifications_default_recipients                        # Whether to use default recipients for assignee notifications
        additional_recipients = var.role_policy_rules.notification_rules_eligible_activations_assignee_notifications_additional_recipients
      }
    }
    active_assignments {
      admin_notifications {
        notification_level    = var.role_policy_rules.notification_rules_active_assignments_admin_notifications_notification_level                     # Notification level for assignee notifications
        default_recipients    = var.role_policy_rules.notification_rules_active_assignments_admin_notifications_default_recipients                         # Whether to use default recipients for assignee notifications
        additional_recipients = var.role_policy_rules.notification_rules_active_assignments_admin_notifications_additional_recipients
      }
      approver_notifications {
        notification_level    = var.role_policy_rules.notification_rules_active_assignments_approver_notifications_notification_level                     # Notification level for assignee notifications
        default_recipients    = var.role_policy_rules.notification_rules_active_assignments_approver_notifications_default_recipients                          # Whether to use default recipients for assignee notifications
        additional_recipients = var.role_policy_rules.notification_rules_active_assignments_approver_notifications_additional_recipients
      }
      assignee_notifications {
        notification_level    = var.role_policy_rules.notification_rules_active_assignments_assignee_notifications_notification_level                     # Notification level for assignee notifications
        default_recipients    = var.role_policy_rules.notification_rules_active_assignments_assignee_notifications_default_recipients                          # Whether to use default recipients for assignee notifications
        additional_recipients = var.role_policy_rules.notification_rules_active_assignments_assignee_notifications_additional_recipients
      }
    }
  }
  timeouts {
    create = "10m"
    delete = "10m"
  }
}

Below is the error I am getting when I try to create above resource.
Error: parsing "/subscriptions/XXXXX-1081-4bff-9256-9feda89161f1/resourceGroups/XXXX-static-rg/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/XXXX-static-kv": parsing segment "providers": parsing the ManagementGroup ID: the segment at position 0 didn't match
│
│ Expected a ManagementGroup ID that matched:
│
│ > /providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/groupIdValue
│
│ However this value was provided:
│
│ > /subscriptions/XXXXX-1081-4bff-9256-9feda89161f1/resourceGroups/XXXX-static-rg/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/XXXX-static-kv
│
│ The parsed Resource ID was missing a value for the segment at position 0
│ (which should be the literal value "providers").
│
│
│
│   with module.pim-assignment-re.azurerm_role_management_policy.role_policy_resource["Contributor"],
│   on pim-assignment-re\role_policy_rule.tf line 6, in resource "azurerm_role_management_policy" "role_policy_resource":
│    6:   scope              = data.azurerm_key_vault.statickv.id           # Scope of the role management policy
│
╵
╷
│ Error: parsing "/subscriptions/XXXXX-1081-4bff-9256-9feda89161f1/resourceGroups/XXXX-static-rg/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/XXXX-static-kv": unexpected segment "providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/XXXX-static-kv" present at the end of the URI (input "/subscriptions/XXXXX-1081-4bff-9256-9feda89161f1/resourceGroups/XXXX-static-rg/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/XXXX-static-kv")
│
│   with module.pim-assignment-re.azurerm_role_management_policy.role_policy_resource["Contributor"],
│   on pim-assignment-re\role_policy_rule.tf line 6, in resource "azurerm_role_management_policy" "role_policy_resource":
│    6:   scope              = data.azurerm_key_vault.statickv.id           # Scope of the role management policy
│
╵
╷
│ Error: parsing "/subscriptions/XXXXX-1081-4bff-9256-9feda89161f1/resourceGroups/XXXX-static-rg/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/XXXX-static-kv": unexpected segment "resourceGroups/XXXX-static-rg/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/XXXX-static-kv" present at the end of the URI (input "/subscriptions/XXXXX-1081-4bff-9256-9feda89161f1/resourceGroups/XXXX-static-rg/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/XXXX-static-kv")
│
│   with module.pim-assignment-re.azurerm_role_management_policy.role_policy_resource["Contributor"],
│   on pim-assignment-re\role_policy_rule.tf line 6, in resource "azurerm_role_management_policy" "role_policy_resource":
│    6:   scope              = data.azurerm_key_vault.statickv.id           # Scope of the role management policy


Is this the last part for assigning at the Key Vault level?

Yes, thats for the key vault resource scope assignment.

Terraform supports only management groups, subscriptions, or resource groups not resource level in the Role Management Policy block. You can refer to the Terraform registry here.


How to configure azurerm_role_management_policy at resource scope?

The error you encountered is because Terraform does not support resource level assignment for Management policies. It only supports management groups, subscriptions, or resource groups, not resource-level in the Role Management Policy block. Refer to the Terraform registry here for more details.

When I try to assign a policy at the Key Vault resource level, I encounter the same error
    provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
    }
    
    data "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
      name                = "venkatvault567"
      resource_group_name = "venkatesan-rg"
    }
    
    data "azurerm_role_definition" "mg_contributor" {
      name  = "Owner"
      scope = data.azurerm_key_vault.example.id
    }
    
    data "azuread_group" "example" {
      display_name     = "Venkatgroup"
      security_enabled = true
    }
    
    
    data "azurerm_role_management_policy" "example" {
      scope              = data.azurerm_key_vault.example.id
      role_definition_id = data.azurerm_role_definition.mg_contributor.id
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_role_management_policy" "example" {
      scope              =  data.azurerm_key_vault.example.id
      role_definition_id = data.azurerm_role_definition.mg_contributor.id
    
      active_assignment_rules {
        expire_after = "P365D"
      }
    
      eligible_assignment_rules {
        expiration_required = false
      }
    
      activation_rules {
        maximum_duration = "PT1H"
        require_approval = true
        approval_stage {
          primary_approver {
            object_id = data.azuread_group.example.object_id
            type      = "Group"
          }
        }
      }
    
      notification_rules {
        eligible_assignments {
          approver_notifications {
            notification_level    = "Critical"
            default_recipients    = false
            additional_recipients = ["someone@example.com"]
          }
        }
        eligible_activations {
          assignee_notifications {
            notification_level    = "All"
            default_recipients    = true
            additional_recipients = ["someone.else@example.com"]
          }
        }
      }
    }

Response:

Reference:  Microsoft.Authorization roleManagementPolicyAssignments
Where can i find role management policies? by VasimTamboli
